# What is the different between these

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using java script , jquery sometime. but I still couldn't figure out proper definitions of below declaration of java script

```
var person = function(){
  name  = "Person1";
  age ="24"
}

function Person (){
  name  = "Perlson1";
  age ="24";     
}

var Person = {
  name : "Person1",
  age : "24",
}
```

Could anyone give me proper explanation to these three type,I am bit confused the way implementing within my project,

I would really appreciate it

Comment: There is no space between `java` and `script`.

Comment: The first two are functions which set the global variables `name` and `age`. The last one is an object literal with two properties `name` and `age`. The first two look very odd and should never be used anywhere. So the difference is: Everything.

Comment: This is a good guide to javascript objects, functions and scope http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/guide

Comment: This is also worth a read: [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var person = function(){
  name  = "Person1";
  age ="24"
}
```

The above code defines a variable 'person', which is assigned an anonymous function that sets the values for 2 global variables 'name' and 'age'.

```
function Person (){
  name  = "Perlson1";
  age ="24";     
}
```

The above code defines a function that sets the values for 2 global variables 'name' and 'age'.
So, syntactically 1st & 2nd are different way of defining the function. But, they serve the same purpose. To access them,
console.log(name); //or console.log(window.name);
console.log(age); //or console.log(window.age);

---

```
var Person = {
  name : "Person1",
  age : "24",
}
```

The above 3rd code block is just an Object. It cannot be called by any other code. This just defines the object Person, which has 2 properties 'name' and 'age'. Note that here, the 2 properties - name and age belong to the Person object and not to the window. i.e. they are not global variables. They are bound to Person object. To access these,
console.log(Person.name);
console.log(Person.age);

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.

In the first two examples, you defined a function, and what the function do is set the values of  two **global variables** `name` and `age`.

The third example is to define a normal object, which has properties with `name` and `age`.

The first two most likely should be below:

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;     
}

var person1 = new Person('Person1', 24);
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that with the first example you could then assign that function dynamically to an object

Comment: @dops: You mean as property value? You can do the same with the second one. After the functions are created, there is no difference between a function expression and a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the same as the second, creating a function named `Person`.

The third however, creates an object called `Person` which has the properties `name` and `age` set.

So using the third,

```
alert(Person.name); // alerts `Person1`
alert(Person.age); // alerts `24`
```